# How do I manage exceptions of pymongo MongoDB connections and free up memory when some of my commands fail?

Tags: mongodb, memory, pymongo

I am using the pymongo driver to connect to a MongoDB data lake where I execute thousands of commands on the hundreds of collections that are stored in there. Some of these commands fail but I just catch the exceptions and move on to the next command. However, after a few hundred failed commands, mongoDB crashes and I need to restart it on the server that hosts the data lake. The log files for mongoDB says `[conn29] out of memory`. Why could this be the case? Are the command fails cause pymongo to establish a new connection every time which causes memory issues? Am I just catching the exceptions badly?

```
mongoDBConnection = pymongo.Client(connectionString)
db = mongoDBConnection.get_database(DBName)
for collection in mongoDBConnection.get_database().list_collection_names():
    for command in command_set:
        try:
            db.command("command": collection)
        except (pymongo.errors.ExecutionTimeout, Exception) as err:
            print("Command {} not executed".format(command))
```

Is it a better idea to close the pymongo connection and open a new one when I catch an exception?

Comment: Generally, a connection is associated with a connection pool (and the related attributes can be tuned) and connections require memory. What kind of commands are you running and do they require memory? These are some considerations. It may be worth looking into the nature of the exceptions also. It is normal to close the connection after its usage is done - to release any resources, like memory.

Comment: The commands are pre-written mongoDB queries stored in the data lake. Is there a way to check how many connections are open using pymongo?

Comment: You can start from here: [FAQ: MongoDB Diagnostics](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/diagnostics/).